# java.lang.IllegalStateException while moving actionbar to toolbar in android

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I have been trying to move action bar in my app to the toolbar. I am getting the following error at run time at the `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` line in my code.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has
an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

I went through many posts on the same issue but nothing seems to be working. Below are the details of my code.

This is my activity on create function

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppMainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
<style name="UItheme" parent="AppTheme"/>
```

Manifest file is something like this

```
<application
        android:theme="@style/AppMainTheme">
        <activity
           android:name="com.android.ui.activities.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/UItheme" >
        </activity>
</application>
```

can someone let me know what the possible issue could be?

Comment: if you are using `AppCompatActivity`( it's not clear from the question) ... use proper, support method for requesting window feature

Comment: @Selvin Yes I am using AppCompat Activity. What do you mean by proper support method?

Comment: Check the documentation

Comment: @Selvin I changed requestWindowFeature to supportRequestWindowFeature and still the issue exists.

Comment: Why you wana use it? it will not work on API >=21 anyway ...

Comment: why do I wanna use what? can you please be more clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142745/discussion-between-ramya-and-selvin).

Comment: Obviously the FLAG

Comment: I even tried removing that still didn't help.

Comment: I suggest that you review [Setting Up the App Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) and double-check that you are doing everything exactly as explained there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following steps

- Extend your activity with AppCompatActivity.
- Comment out the line requestWindowFeature
- Declare the theme for your activity in manifest file.

  ```
   <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
  </activity>
  ```
- Define following snippet in your styles.xml
  `<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
      <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
      <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>`